# Gluon Application won't run on Mobile and getting Blackscreen

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

i get a Blackscreen when i start the app on my Device.

My Device: Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro
JDK = 8u231

Comment: Are you running Android 10? To find out about possible exceptions, use `adb logcat`.

Comment: Yes Android 10 ^^

Comment: This is the issue: https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/issues/38, it shows a possible workaround at the end. Another option: use the Client plugin with JDK 11+ (see https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples)

Comment: Do you have Android Studio installed? If you have please edit the question and include the error in Logcat window by filter only errors. This tool give you more easy to see what happen in Android system.